# Version control for tickets?

Tags: git, version-control, agile

*Conceptually related to the independent content-hosting with Git [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007679/how-can-i-host-git-repositories-and-manage-my-content-hosting-myself).*

I would like to separate 3 things: ticketing -version-control (management), programming -version-control and structural -version-control (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253615/structure-of-projects-in-version-control-something-like-maven-for-non-java-pro)). Now everyone  should be able to see tickets and how they have evolved from an idea into a code/product. Currently, I have large problems because tickets are in proprietary coffins in Bitbucket and Github, apparently their business strategy to lock users. I want to manage my tickets in some repository -- related tickets [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/51), [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/57) and [here](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/issues/52). If I do a ticket, I want to commit that. I want to keep track of my tickets also because I want to be able to change the provider later easily. Github has some good features such as punch -cards (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251941/how-can-i-see-github-style-things-such-as-punchcards-and-timeline-of-git-repo)) but otherwise harder to use over Bitbucket. I want to control my tickets and add features whenever I want to. So how can I have a version-control over tickets?

```
   |---> tickets' version-control (Ticgit -version-not-yet-exist)
   |
---|---> code's VC (git)
   |
   |---> structural VC (? maven ?? runs, deployes, ??)
   | 
   |---> perms' VC (Gitolite)
```

**Perhaps related**

> 1. [Version control for version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437247/version-control-for-version-control)
> 2. [Structure of Projects in Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829/structure-of-projects-in-version-control)
> 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952/database-version-control

Comment: What is the actual question here.

Comment: @Daenyth: nothing, stupid question -- probably tried to reinvent the wheel, ticgit/gitolite/etc should be enough. Perhaps-related threads contained misleading threads, not about git but svn and a lot of poor material, got misguided.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is: it reads more like a statement of intent than a question. But assuming you're looking for a system that lets you do that, you might be interested in [ticgit](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit), a bug-tracking system that uses a Git branch as a backend, letting you fork and branch the bug tracking data at the same time as forking the code.

Comment: It's great to hear that you're using it. Don't hesitate to create new questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Roger, I moved the milestone q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251480/how-to-use-milestones-in-ticgit), I cannot yet understand how to use them. In the same q, I am touching the issues actualy how to use the ticgit, I am sure it is a small issue but irritating because cannot get it running...